# Solve the IVP $\vec{y'}=A\vec{y}\ $ given $\ (A-I)\vec{v}\ $ and $\ (A-I)^2\vec{v}$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
> 5 & -2 & -7 \\ 
> -4 & 3 & 4 \\ 
> 6 & -3 & -8  
> \end{pmatrix} $ and $\vec{v}=\left(\begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right)$.

The first part of the problem asked to calculate $(A-I)\vec{v}$ and $(A-I)^2\vec{v}$, which I calculated to be $\left(\begin{array}{c} -1 \\ -2 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)$ and $\vec{0}$ respectively.

The question then asks to solve the initial value problem $\vec{y'}=A\vec{y}$ with $\vec{y}(0)=\vec{v}$.

I don't understand how to use what we calculated in the earlier part to help to solve this initial value problem. I determined from first principles that the eigenvalues are $\lambda=1,1,-2$ and I know that the solution of our initial value problem will take the form $\vec{y}=e^{tA}\vec{v}\ $, but I don't quite understand the significance of $(A-I)\vec{v}$ and $(A-I)^2\vec{v}$.

Comment: Usually when you're considering higher powers of $A-I$ the geometric multiplicity of that eigenvalue  is lower than the algebraic multiplicity. You want to solve $(A-I)v=0$ to get $v_1\neq 0$ and $(A-I)v=v_1$ to get $v_2\neq 0$. Only writing one half of what you're solving can hurt your progress /correctness :-)

Comment: Why do we do this though? I still don't understand the significance of $(A-I)\vec{v}$ and $(A-I)^2\vec{v}$. Why does this help solve the IVP and not how. The result will follow more easily if I understand every aspect of the question.

Comment: Probably the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ will have only a single associated eigenvector. Thus to find the solution you will have to resort to generalized eigenvectors (which is the $v$ described in N8trom's comment).

Comment: Does the solution of $(A-I)\vec{v}$ correspond to an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda=1$?

Comment: Did your textbook or instructor not explain all of this?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. We rely upon course notes provided by the lecturer and none of this was explained.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your IVP can be [formulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Linear_differential_equation_systems) in terms of the exponential of the matrix $A$ as $y(t) = \exp(At) v$. Now, let's rewrite this as $y(t) = \exp(It + (A-I)t)v = \exp(It)\exp((A-I)t)v$, where $I$ denotes unit matrix. The first term $\exp(It)$ is just a $\exp(t)$ multiple of the unit matrix. As for the second term:

$$ \exp((A-I)t)v = (I + (A-I)t + \frac{1}{2}(A-I)^2t^2 + \ldots\,)\,v $$

Since $(A-I)^2v$ yields zero vector, all the higher terms in the matrix exponential will be zero as well.

Thus in total:

$$ y(t) = \exp(t)\bigl( v + t\,(A-I)v + \frac{t^2}{2}\,(A-I)^2v\bigr)$$